# EXCEL: Extract text in string NOT between 2 characters

Tags: excel, text

I need to extract JUST THE PERSONS NAME from the string below.  What function would I use in Excel?

Example:

```
Jane Doe <email@email.com>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tried something with `LEFT` and `FIND` already?

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample of your data so we have something to work on? The solution to your problem depends on how the information is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you had for sample data before, the `LEFT` function combined with the `FIND` function will do what you need. Something like

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("<",A1,1)-2)
```

Breaking down what this does from the inside out:

```
FIND("<",A1,1)-2)
```

This tells it to find the first instance of the "<" character in the specified cell (A1), starting from and including the first character. It will return the position of that character. So with the text it's looking in being `Jane Doe <email@email.com>` it would return 10, substracting 2 to say we don't want that actual character and we don't want the space before it.

So with that in mind our formula looks like:

```
=LEFT(A1, 8)
```

Which means get 8 characters, starting from the leftmost character, from the specified cell (A1). Resulting in `Jane Doe`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
=LEFT(F3,FIND(" <",F3))

=FIND(" <",F3)
```

This will find the first instance of the character " <" in the text.

After that our formula will look like this:

> =LEFT(F3.9)

which means we'll get 9 characters left and this will return:

Jane Doe